# Windows mobile autoresize with panels

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, autosize

I've got an app which will run on two different devices - one with a screen size of 240x320, the other 480x640.

For all forms bar one the VS generated code is fine:

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
this.AutoScroll = true;
```

For one form i'm capturing a signature. I'm doing this by a panel with a graphics handler; capturing mouse down and move events; this generates a list of vector points which I can draw lines with.

On the smaller res screen this is fine. On the higher res, I can't display my lines.. and I think this is because the panel is beyond the windows form size.

The form is created with a size of 240 x 268; a standard size I think - i've not manually set it, VS does this for me.

In order to get the panel in the right spot on the high res device, the co-ordinates are 3, 290; ie, 290 is past 268. Also the width of the panel is 448 which is somewhat larger than 240.

I'm using .net 2.0 (can't use later). I think I need to resize the form to make it larger but I do want to keep the existing re-sizing for the other controls on the form.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer for the benefit of those who may have a similar problem in the future. PaulG pointed me in the right direction but I found the root cause to be something else.

The PDA project i've got uses "FormFactor WindowsMobile 6 Classic" which has a default size of 240 x 268.

Changing this to "Windows Mobile 6 Professional VGA" created a much larger form size.

This allowed me to get things positioned correctly for the larger size; then AutoScaleMode to DPI; and manually resizing the panel smaller made it all work.

IE, going from larger to smaller was easy; I didn't get smaller to larger working.

Answer (score 1):

Make the form dock to fill, then use the `Anchor` properties to ensure controls inside the form resize as expected.

If you want the option of customizing how an individual control resizes, then DONT set the anchor properties on it, and instead handle the `Resize` event and perform custom resizing/repositioning within code there.

eg

```
private void form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Center the control without changing width. Other controls are anchored.
    this.control.Left = (this.Width - this.control.Width) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Ok.. so say my panel is 200 x 100 for the small form and 448 x 200 for the larger. So I can use the resize event to specify the size I need. Perhaps I try docking it to the bottom ? The panel is the only item that's not resizing now. And oddly, the mouse down events are still being triggered and my vector points being filled.. just the line drawing not working. Will try the resize and see how that goes - thanks.